# C++03 check if template parameter is void?

Tags: c++

Consider a function

```
template <typename Ret>
Ret function(...) {
    Ret a;
    // . . . do something with a
    return a;
}
```

If I call this as

```
function<void>();
```

the compiler says

> error: variable or field 'a' declared void
>
> error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]

How do I enforce a check on in this function, for instance

```
template <typename Ret>
Ret function(...) {
    // if (Ret is void) return;
    Ret a;
    // . . . do something with a
    return a;
}
```

I know C++11 has `std::is_void` and `std::is_same`

```
bool same = std::is_same<Ret, void>::value;
```

Anything in C++03 ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest would be to provide a template specialization for `void`. You'd need to do similar stuff even in C++11, since an early `return` doesn't stop the compiler from enforcing type rules on the rest of the function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just specialize, or write your own `is_same`, that's pretty easy, or of course you can use not-standard libraries (for example boost).

Specialization

```
template<typename Ret>
Ret function(...)
{
   Ret a;
   // ...
   return a;
}

template<>
void function<void>(...)
{
}
```

Own

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
   static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

BTW with `is_same` it's not so simple, that you think. You also need specialization, or overloading

```
template<typename Ret>
typename enable_if<!is_same<Ret, void>::value, Ret>::type
function(...)
{
   Ret a;
   // ...
   return a;
}

template<typename Ret>
typename enable_if<is_same<Ret, void>::value, Ret>::type
function(...)
{
}
```

So, just specialization is more simple.

Comment: Didn't know that `std::is_same` can be implemented so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A runtime `if` would not be enough, all instantiations of a template must be compilable. In your case, a specialisation might be the best course of action:

```
template <typename Ret>
Ret function(...) {
    Ret a;
    // . . . do something with a
    return a;
}

template <>
void function<void>(...) {
    return;
}
```

Also, there is [`boost::is_same`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html) available for C++03.