# Write version specific C++ code to detect symbol in std namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my recent [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31455598/2425366), I was suggested to implement my own `is_same` for C++03 since the standard version is a part of C++11. The implementation was

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same <T, T> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

I want that it **should be used only if it is not defined in the `std` namespace**. For instance, can it be wrapped in a preprocessor block like this ?

```
#if !defined(std::is_same)
// define is_same here
#endif
```

I want to avoid these errors

> error: 'is_same' is not a member of 'std'     // C++03
>
> error: reference to 'is_same' is ambiguous    // C++11

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)

Comment: @Mikhail I mentioned that I have used `__cplusplus`, but it doesn't help in windows platform.

Comment: From what I see, it should be defined. It seems like it is not correctly defined, though: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763051/a-value-of-predefined-macro-cplusplus-is-still-199711l

Comment: Why not to let the build system handle things like checking the compiler, e.g. using [CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14934542)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't detect whether your implementation provides `std::is_same`, because that would mean including `<type_traits>`, which does not exist in C++03. Even if you could get around that obstacle, the metaprogramming contortions needed to detect it would not be worth it.

The best you can do is to heuristically check a combination of predefined macros:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || _MSC_VER >= 1400 || defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
    #include <type_traits>
    #define HAS_STD_IS_SAME
#endif

namespace your_project
{
    #ifdef HAS_STD_IS_SAME
        using std::is_same;
    #else
        template <typename T, typename U> struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };
        template <typename T> struct is_same <T, T> { static const bool value = true; };
    #endif
}
```

But there is nil benefit in doing this, because all implementations will implement `is_same` in the same manner as the one you have provided, anyway.